# Algolia - WordPress, Only show certain category within one CPT (index)

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have installed Algolia plugin, created template as per documentation and added I am calling all the items from the index of given CPT. Is there any settings that would allow me to pull only from certain category/term?

var search = instantsearch({
  appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  indexName: 'rb_posts_it-blog',
  urlSync: true
});

I have not found this anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms are by default flagged as [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/?language=php), which mean you can easily filter on them.

Here is an example of how you would filter based on categories. Depending on the type of widget you use, you will need to remove the filters you don't need:

```
var search = instantsearch({
  [...],
  searchParameters: {
    hierarchicalFacetsRefinements: { // menu is implemented as a hierarchicalFacetsRefinements
      categories: ['Cell Phones']
    },
    facetsRefinements: {
      isPremium: [true]
    },
    disjunctiveFacetsRefinements: {
      brand: ['Samsung', 'Apple']
    },
    // Add to "facets" all attributes for which you
    // do NOT have a widget defined
    facets: ['isPremium']
  },
});
// Below is just a common widget configuration, to show
// how it interacts with the above searchParameters
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.menu({
    [...],
    attributeName: 'categories'
  })
);
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
    attributeName: 'brand',
    operator: 'or'
  })
);
```

Full docs about customizing default filters are available here: https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#default-filters

Comment: Yes this sounds like pre-set category on certain filter. I do not want any UI to appear, I just want them to be able to only search within one specific category. So I have 6 categories, but I do not want to show any as if there is no choice and only allow to search within certain category.

Comment: Ok the answer is correct. It is worth to mention that there are two key elements you need to watch in this case: hierarchicalFacetsRefinements: categories that then targets search widget with attributeName: 'categories'.

Comment: Another useful link to only display childrens of certain categories and how to do it is here: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/830 - so: ['Revêtement > Éléments de décor > Poignées de portes']